# Is there a default windows path for vb?

Tags: vb.net

So im just wondering, in batch they have a default way of saying the original drive or folderpath like so: `%drive%` for your `C:\` drive or whatever your drive is or like `%windir%` for the windows directory. I need this to extract files into the windows folder and some people might have a `D:\` drive instead of `C:\` or `Windows.001` instead of Windows. Is there a way for this in vb 2008-2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [System.Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) using the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) enumeration. Or you can use [System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx) if you know the Environment Variable's name.

From last link:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir")
```

Comment: @MarkChai Glad to have helped

Answer (score 2):

To get to a folder in the root directory: when calling the file path, instead of asking for: "C:\Root Folder You Want\" Use: "\Root Folder You Want\".

But it varies between system because people have different folders (ex. Program Files vs. Program Files(x86)), in which case you could use a System.Environment function to find what OS Version they're running, etc.

You can find documentation on this here: [Environment Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yat6s6yb.aspx)

In Visual Studio, you can also go to the EDIT menu and then select INSERT SNIPPET, which has some very useful and easily customizable Environment methods.